# How to create fragmented sitemap xml with gsitemap on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, seo, prestashop, sitemap, prestashop-1.6

I'm with a Prestashop 1.6 and its default sitemap.xml module (`gsitemap`) can create fragmented sitemaps based on the number of sites (shops) that contains the prestashop installation.

I have only one shop, but multiple categories with thousands of products. I need to create fragmented sitemaps (with its index) **based on product categories available**.

For example:

```
- sitemap-index.xml
   - sitemap-dogs.xml
   - sitemap-cats.xml
   - sitemap-birds.xml
   - sitemap-others.xml
```

Did you find any simple solution, or module, to achieve this, instead of remake all the default module?

Thank you.

Comment: You should buy a module with those kind of sitemap index already implemented, this one for instance : https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/seo-referencement-naturel/20903-sitemap-simple-multiboutique-multilangue-et-blogs.html

Comment: I was developed the module by myself. I will publish here for helping anothers on the future. No price! Thankyou.